# Read data and convert to json format with some specific format

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am reading csv file and converting it into json file but I need to create "address" field out of the data as array field. I have written the code for it but could not make it as array.
All the address related field comes under address column which is an array field.

**Input file**

```
"source_id"|"first_name"|"last_name"|"address_type"|"address_line_1"|"city"
"41614335"|Reinaldo|Tonkoski Jr.|Primary|Deh 211 Box 2222|Brookings|
"41614335"|Reinaldo|Tonkoski Jr.|home|"2409 10th St Apt 123"|Brookings
"07605348"|E|Christodoulou|Primary|"4D Ag Lavras st"|Kifissia
"07605348"|E|Christodoulou|home|"131 N Hamilton Dr Apt 308"|Beverly Hills
```

**Output Getting**

```
[
   {
      "source_id":7605348,
      "first_name":"E",
      "last_name":"Christodoulou",
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "address_type":"Primary",
            "address_line_1":"4D Ag Lavras st",
            "city":"Kifissia"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "source_id":7605348,
      "first_name":"E",
      "last_name":"Christodoulou",
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "address_type":"home",
            "address_line_1":"131 N Hamilton Dr Apt 308",
            "city":"Beverly Hills"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Expecsted Output :**

```
[
   {
      "source_id":7605348,
      "first_name":"E",
      "last_name":"Christodoulou",
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "address_type":"Primary",
            "address_line_1":"4D Ag Lavras st",
            "city":"Kifissia"
         },
         {
            "address_type":"home",
            "address_line_1":"131 N Hamilton Dr Apt 308",
            "city":"Beverly Hills"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "source_id":41614335,
      "first_name":"Reinaldo",
      "last_name":"Tonkoski Jr.",
      "parsed_address":[
         {
            "address_type":"Primary",
            "address_line_1":"Deh 211 Box 2222",
            "city":"Kifissia"
         },
         {
            "address_type":"home",
            "address_line_1":"2409 10th St Apt 123",
            "city":"Beverly Hills"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**code tried**

```
df = pd.read_csv("file")
g_cols = ['source_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']
cols = ['address_type', 'address_line_1', 'city']
# Handling Address fields
df2 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(
        name="parsed_address").to_dict('record')

    # Removing duplicate entry in address field
    for i in range(0, len(df2)):
        final_list = [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in df2[i]["parsed_address"])]
        df2[i]["parsed_address"] = final_list

    # Convert resultant list to pandas dataframe
    df22 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
    print(df22)
```

Comment: Hey, have you posted partial code for this? I seem to get a key error for source_id when running this code.

Comment: Posted partial code because implemented code form some other requirement as well but this code well defined the the issue. Can you please let me know what exact error you getting out of this code.

Comment: Yeah it says KeyError: 'source_id' at line 7 df2 = df.drop()...

Comment: Please put line here. Please check spelling in input data and code

Comment: not sure why throwing this error. Can you please check my code and let me know what i am missing in the code to get address field correct in json output

Comment: df2 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(g_cols)[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).reset_index(
        name="parsed_address").to_dict('record')

this line gives the said error

Comment: @sujalsingh, Not sure why it is throwing error. I am not getting any error out of this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic_address =[]
for source, group in df.groupby(by=["source_id"]):

    address_dic = {}
    address_dic["source_id"] = source
    address_dic["address"] = group.drop(columns=["source_id", "first_name", "last_name").to_dict("record")
    dic_address.append(address_dic)
    print(dic_address)

    df_add = pd.DataFrame(dic_address)

    listval = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    
    df_source_group = df.drop_duplicates().groupby("source_id")[listval].agg(
        lambda x: ','.join(set(x))).reset_index().to_dict('record')
    
    df22 = pd.DataFrame(df_source_group)
    df_merge = pd.merge(df_add,df22)
```